# Error onclientclick event - Handles clause requires WithEvents

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this close button with onclientclick event which is giving me this error. It works in some pages and doesn't work in anothers. I cannot figure out why. There is a blue underline after Handles in the code page.

```
<asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btnclass" />
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btnclass" OnClientClick="btnClose_Click()" />

Protected Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
    Me.Dispose()
    Response.Redirect("~/SearchForm.aspx", False)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnClientClick` is the javascript code that should be executed when you click on the button on client-side. But you are handling the `Button.Click`-event which is a serverside event.

Therefore this button needs to be created with [`WithEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf7ebaz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) (in VB.NET) which is done automatically if you add a button in the designer.

So there must be somewhere in the codebehind class (or in the `aspx.designer.vb` file) this:

```
Dim WithEvents btnClose As New Button
```

You can also add the event handler on the aspx page instead of via [`Handles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k46st1y.aspx):

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="btnclass" 
    OnClick="btnClose_Click" 
    OnClientClick="btnClose_ClientClick()" />
```

Note that `btnClose_ClientClick` is the js-code which can be a js-function. By the way, if you want to prevent the postback  from client-side return `false` from `OnClientClick`:

```
OnClientClick="return btnClose_ClientClick();"
```

( presuming  that `btnClose_ClientClick` returns a `bool` )

Comment: OMG Thanks Tim, it worked. I add the Dim statement in the code page and just used onclick event and the magic worked. Thanks a bunch.